# What does the classifying space of a topological monoid classify?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, classifying-spaces

The classifying space $BG$ of a topological group $G$ classifies principal $G$ bundles. I have come to appreciate this.

I hope the following question is appropriate for MathOverflow:

What does the classifying space of a topological monoid classify?

Comment: The classifying space of a topological monoid is equivalent to the classifying space of its group completion, so it certainly classifies principal bundles on the group completion. I don't know if you can make it more explicit than that.

Comment: @DenisNardin: What if the monoid is non-commutative?

Comment: If the monoid does not have a calculus of fractions, the group completion is kind of horrifying to compute, but it still exists and it is a topological group (note that it might well, nay it will, be infinite dimensional even if $M$ is discrete, but such is life).

Comment: To clarify: I mean the group completion as an $E_1$-space, but Quillen has shown that all group-like $E_1$-spaces can be represented by topological groups, so in the end we have a homotopy equivalence $BM\cong BG$ for $G$ some topological group.

Comment: @DenisNardin: have some reading to do. Where do I learn about $E_1$ spaces?

Comment: I don't think you need to learn a lot about $E_1$-spaces for understanding this story. I suggest you start with Quillen's *On the group completion of a simplicial monoid* and, if you're still unsatisfied by that, I recommend reading Adams' book *Infinite loop spaces*, at least until he defines $E_n$-spaces. But this is probably not going to give you a very satisfying answer to your original question because $G$ in general is very unexplicit (which is also why those are comments and not an answer :))

Comment: Section 5 of Segal's *Classifying spaces related to foliations* shows that for discrete $M$ the space $BM$ still classifies principal $M$-bundles. In Moerdijk's *Classifying spaces and classifying topoi* there is a kind of answer for general topological monoids (Cor IV.4.5) if you specialize from topological categories (restricting to those with just one object), but it is not in terms of principal bundles. His version with principal bundles (Section IV.2) has again a discreteness condition.

Comment: @LennartMeier: Thanks I will look at it the next time I'm in Utrecht (we don't have a library with math books...). If you post this as an answer I will accept this.

Comment: Related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/23857/what-does-the-classifying-space-of-a-category-classify

Comment: Although predated by Moerdijk's book by several years, you may enjoy reading Maichael Weiss's paper *What does the classifying space of a category classify?* for a thorough discussion of the even more general problem. In brief, "...classifies sheaves whose values are contravariant functors from that category to sets and whose stalks are representable."

Comment: @DenisNardin wrote: "The classifying space of a topological monoid is equivalent to the classifying space of its group completion."   I don't think that's true; for example here is a 5-element discrete monoid whose classifying space is $S^2$: https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0202260.  Its group completion must be some discrete group $G$, with classifying space the Eilenberg-Mac Lane space $K(G,1)$, but $S^2$ is not a $K(G,1)$.

Comment: @JohnBaez I meant its group completion as $E_1$-space

Comment: Are you saying the group completion of this 5-element discrete monoid as an $E_1$-space has a classifying space that's homotopy equivalent to $S^2$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Section 5 of Segal's [Classifying spaces related to foliations](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82283884.pdf) shows that for discrete monoids $M$ the space $BM$ still classifies principal $M$-bundles (in a suitable sense). In Moerdijk's *Classifying spaces and classifying topoi* there is a kind of answer for general topological monoids (Cor IV.4.5); it is not in terms of principal bundles though, but rather in terms of linear orders. (He formulates it for topological categories, but topological monoids are just topological categories with one object.) His version with principal bundles (Section IV.2) has again a discreteness condition.