# References on principal $\mathbf{C}$-bundles, where $\mathbf{C}$ is a category?

Tags: reference-request, sheaf-theory, principal-bundles, covering-spaces

Is there any treatment on principal "categorical" bundles - principal $\mathbf{C}$-bundles, where $\mathbf{C}$ is some (topological) category?

I know that one can define "categorical covering spaces" - locally constant $\mathbf{C}$-valued sheaves on a topological space $X$. I think that there's a nice equivalence of categories of the form

$$\left\{\text{Locally constant } \mathbf{C}-\text{sheaves on }X \right\} \leftrightarrow [\Pi_1(X), \mathbf{C}]$$

where $\Pi_1(X)$ is the fundamental groupoid of $X$ and $[\_,\_]$ is the functor category.

Is there a general notion of principal $\mathbf{C}-$bundle that captures this particular case? Is there any hope of a nice result in the form of a bijection

$$\left\{ \text{Principal } \mathbf{C}-\text{bundles on } X \text{ up to iso} \right\} \leftrightarrow [X, B \mathbf{C}]$$

where $[X, B\mathbf{C}]$ represents homotopy classes of maps from $X$ to the classifying space of the category $\mathbf{C}$?

Comment: You might find this question helpful https://mathoverflow.net/questions/23857/what-does-the-classifying-space-of-a-category-classify

Comment: Also this https://ivv5hpp.uni-muenster.de/u/mweis_02/preprints/catnotes.pdf

Comment: Your hope is only possible when $\mathbf C$ is a groupoid. Otherwise, maps from $\Pi_1 X$ to $\mathbf C$ only depend on the maximal subgroupoid of $\mathbf C$, while maps from $X$ to $B\mathbf C$ only depend on the ($\infty$-)groupoid completion of $\mathbf C$.

Comment: For $C$ a topological groupoid, this is a well-established structure with plenty of older references. See, e.g. Def. 61 in https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0306176.pdf, or the nlab-page https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/groupoid+principal+bundle, or Section 2.2 in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1103.4815.pdf.

Answer (score 4):

Such a notion of a principal $\def\bC{{\bf C}}\bC$-bundle (when $\bC$ is a topological or simplicial category, or a Segal space) is available in Definition 6.1 of the paper [Classifying spaces of infinity-sheaves](https://arxiv.org/abs/1912.10544).

It works as expected: the cocycle data of a $\bC$-bundle on $X$ is given by an open cover $\{U_i\}_{i∈I}$ of $X$ together with maps $U_i→{\bf Ob}(\bC)$, $U_i∩U_j→{\bf Mor}(\bC)$, etc., which must satisfy the appropriate higher coherence conditions, expressed via the Čech nerve.  Some care must be exercised since $B\bC$ inverts all morphisms in $\bC$, which can be taken into account by modifying the Čech nerve appropriately.

Then one can define the space of $\bC$-bundles over $X$ (Definition 6.4)
and prove that this space is a representable ∞-sheaf with respect to $X$.
When $X$ is a manifold, this is proved in Theorem 6.6 of op. cit.
When $X$ is an arbitrary topological space, one can instead cite Theorem 8.5 of [Numerable open covers and representability of topological stacks](https://arxiv.org/abs/2203.03120), where open covers used to define $\bC$-bundles must be numerable.

Comment: So a principal $\mathbf C$-bundle is the same thing as a principal $\operatorname{iso}(\mathbf C)$-bundle, where $\operatorname{iso}(\mathbf C)\to\mathbf C$ is universal among ∞-groupoids mapping to $\mathbf C$?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე: No, it's the other adjoint (invert morphisms up to homotopy, not discard the noninvertible ones).  This is natural since this is what the functor $B$ does anyway.

Comment: Is not what you describe a functor from the nerve of $\{U\}$ *to* $\mathbf C$?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე: No, it is not.  It is a functor from the modified Čech nerve of $\{U_i\}_{i∈I}$ to $\bf C$.  The latter is introduced in Definition 6.1 and has the disjoint union of all finite intersections as objects, and their inclusions as morphisms.

Comment: Oh wow that's interesting! Thanks. This seems to be a new notion, have not seen it before. So this modified nerve is not equivalent to any kind of groupoid?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე: For example, take an open cover with two elements $\{U,V\}$.  The the modified Čech nerve is the category internal to topological spaces whose nonidentity morphisms look like $U←U∩V→V$, and are not invertible.

Comment: I see, thanks. One more question. I am aware of another notion of principal bundle that does not force to invert anything, do you know if it is related? I mean the version in "ordinary" category theory: a $\mathbf C$-torsor in $\mathcal E$ is a functor $\mathbf C\to\mathcal E$ whose Grothendieck construction is a (co?)filtered internal category of $\mathcal E$.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე: Inversion of morphisms only happens once you pass to the space of $\bf C$-bundles.  If you consider a single $\bf C$-bundle, then it certainly sees noninvertible morphisms, as indicated above.  What is $\cal E$ in the above comment?  Is there a reference for this notion of a bundle?

Comment: Yes it is quite old. Here $\mathcal E$ is a (Grothendieck) topos. It is the content of Diaconescu's theorem that the category of geometric morphisms from $\mathcal E$ to the presheaf topos of $\mathbf C$ is equivalent to the category of such torsors. It may be found already in Johnstone's first (1977) topos theory book, Theorem 4.34 there (page 113).

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე: Yes, I see now.  The notion described in my answer is essentially the homotopy coherent analogue of the construction described in Johnstone's book.  This is also the construction used by Moerdijk in his book “Classifying Spaces and Classifying Topoi”, and also by Weiss in his paper.  Roughly, a $\def\bC{{\bf C}}\bC$-bundle over $X$ is an ∞-flat functor $\def\Sh{{\sf Sh}}\bC→\Sh(X)$, where $\Sh(X)$ is the ∞-topos of ∞-sheaves on $X$.  To extract such a functor from the above construction, send $A∈\bC$ to the ∞-sheaf given by mapping the Čech cocycle data into $A$.

Comment: Great, thanks! Where would you recommend to read about ∞-flatness?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე: The only source I am aware of is Section 5.3.2 in Lurie's Higher Topos Theory.

Answer (score 2):

You may find the following paper relevant, by thinking of your topological groupoid as a topological $2$-category with a single object (and invertible $2$-morphisms).  The geometric nerve discussed there classifies the corresponding principal $2$-bundles.

```
Baas, Nils A.; Bökstedt, Marcel; Kro, Tore August
Two-categorical bundles and their classifying spaces.
J. K-Theory 10 (2012), no. 2, 299–369.
```

https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0612549

It generalizes

```
Baas, Nils A.; Dundas, Bjørn Ian; Rognes, John
Two-vector bundles and forms of elliptic cohomology.
Topology, geometry and quantum field theory, 18–45,
London Math. Soc. Lecture Note Ser., 308, Cambridge Univ. Press, Cambridge, 2004.
```

https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0306027

In the presence of a symmetric monoidal structure that you might want to group complete with respect to, the following two papers may be relevant:

```
Baas, Nils A.; Dundas, Bjørn Ian; Richter, Birgit; Rognes, John
Stable bundles over rig categories.
J. Topol. 4 (2011), no. 3, 623–640.
```

https://arxiv.org/abs/0909.1742

```
Baas, Nils A.; Dundas, Bjørn Ian; Richter, Birgit; Rognes, John
Ring completion of rig categories.
J. Reine Angew. Math. 674 (2013), 43–80.
```

https://arxiv.org/abs/0706.0531

(Apologies for the self-promotion.)

Comment: Dear John, you seem to be one level "too high". A topological 2-category with a single object is a topological *2-group*, which is more then a topological *groupoid*. The question is about ordinary bundles, not about 2-bundles.